# How to format Date received from Element-UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm making use of the datepicker from Element Ui where the user can select a range in dates. When the user fills in the datepicker, this is what I get back: `['2018-01', '2019-02']` . So just an array with two String elements. NOT a `Date()` object.

When dynamically outputting this to the user, I would like to show it as: `January 2018 - February 2019`

I got it somewhat working in my project but the code just really sucks and also doesn't work properly either. Checkout this [gif](https://gyazo.com/426c70277cc1fd4946feed571d89671d) of my current project and somewhat desired result. I was wondering if someone knows a good and easy way of achieving my desired result without too much hassle. I cannot use methods like `toLocaleDateString()` because it isn't a `Date()` object. I've got my code working in a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-wnwzu). If any if you guys knows a solution feel free to edit the listed Codesandbox, I would highly highly appreciate it!

In the Codesandbox I got a computed property `formateDate`. The basic idea of the computed property is to cut the elements of the array I get back from the `datepicker` before and after the `-` effectively giving me the first & second month and first & second year. That data I store in these variables:

```
let monthOne;
let monthTwo;
let yearOne;
let yearTwo;
```

Since I get the months back as `'01'` and `'02'` for example, I created an array of objects to transform the `'01'` and `'02'` to `January` and `February` with a for loop. I then store the result in a new variable with:

```
displayDate = monthOne + ' ' + yearOne + ' - ' + monthTwo + ' ' + yearTwo;
```

Lastly, I tried to store that result into the `timeperiodDisplayString` at the correct index in the `experience` array of objects. Anyway, I'm probably overcomplicating this way to hard so I would REALLY appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Dit you have a look at https://momentjs.com/ ? With this you can easly wrap it in a moment/date object convert it in the string you want

Comment: I did take a look at it, got a better solution working though luckily. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could map over the result from the datepicker component to create an array of Date objects. So you can use `toLocaleDateString()`

Something like this should work:

```
['2018-01', '2019-02'].map((date) => { 
    const split = date.split('-'); 

    return new Date(split[0], +split[1] - 1); 
});
```

Comment: Something along these lines finally worked for my. Thank you for your insight :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse() function from javascript.

```
 var d = Date.parse("2019-01");
 console.log(new Date(d));
```